# Free/open-source lib for .NET to interpret SQL-like filter clause

Tags: library, .net, sql

We'd like to provide our users with the ability to enter filter expressions like "x > 10" or "(x IN ('A', 'B', 'D')) OR (x = 'Z')" and then test whether a string matches the user filter expression.

Can anybody suggest a good free or even open-source library we can use for this purpose in our WinForms.NET project?